# how to use popup and action together in href tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to open a cart modal (popup which includes the item you just clicked  i am trying like this

```
    <a class="btnLink"  data-rel="popup" data-transition="slidedown" href="?action=addToCart&PROD_ID=<?php echo $row["PROD_ID"]; ?>#cart">Add to cart</a></in>
```

this is the part i want to open in popup but only to able to perform popup but not able to perform action

```
<div id="cart">
<?php
// initializ shopping cart class
include 'Cart.php';
$cart = new Cart;
include 'db_const.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !empty($_REQUEST['action'])){
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'addToCart' && !empty($_REQUEST['PROD_ID'])){
        $productID = $_REQUEST['PROD_ID'];
        // get product details
        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM RETAIL_STORE_PROD WHERE PROD_ID = '$productID'";
          $result = db2_prepare($conn, $stmt);
          db2_execute($result);
        $row = db2_fetch_assoc($result);

        $itemData = array(
            'PROD_ID' => $row['PROD_ID'],
            'PROD_NM' => $row['PROD_NM'],
            'MRP' => $row['MRP'],
            'qty' => 1
        );

        $insertItem = $cart->insert($itemData);
        //$redirectLoc = $insertItem?'viewCart.php';
        //header("Location: ".$redirectLoc);
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'updateCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['PROD_ID'])){
        $itemData = array(
            'rowid' => $_REQUEST['PROD_ID'],
            'qty' => $_REQUEST['qty']
        );
        $updateItem = $cart->update($itemData);
        echo $updateItem?'ok':'err';die;
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'removeCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['PROD_ID'])){
        $deleteItem = $cart->remove($_REQUEST['PROD_ID']);
        header("Location: viewCart.php");
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'placeOrder' && $cart->total_items() > 0 && !empty($_SESSION['sessCustomerID'])){
        // insert order details into database
           // insert order items into database
           // $insertOrderItems = $db->multi_query($sql);



    }
}


?>
   <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css<script>
    function updateCartItem(obj,PROD_ID){
        $.get("cartAction.php", {action:"updateCartItem", PROD_ID:PROD_ID, qty:obj.value}, function(data){
            if(data == 'ok'){
                location.reload();
            }else{
                alert('Cart update failed, please try again.');
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
    <table border="0" class="table_fields"  id="t01" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="20px" style="width:100%">

        <tr class="table_fields_top">
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>

    <tbody>
        <?php
        if($cart->total_items() > 0){
            //get cart items from session
            $cartItems = $cart->contents();
            foreach($cartItems as $item){
        ?>
        <tr class="table_fields_top">
            <td><?php echo $item["PROD_NM"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo 'Rs'.$item["MRP"].' '; ?></td>

            <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo $item["qty"]; ?>" onchange="updateCartItem(this, '<?php echo $item["rowid"]; ?>')"></td>
            <td><?php echo 'Rs'.$item["subtotal"].''; ?></td>
            <td>
                <!--<a href="cartAction.php?action=updateCartItem&id=" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>-->
                <a href="cartAction.php?action=removeCartItem&PROD_ID=<?php echo $item["rowid"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><img border="0" alt="Delete_button.png" src="Delete_button.png" width="50" height="50"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } }else{ ?>
        <tr><td colspan="5"><p>Your cart is empty.....</p></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="billing.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></i> <img src="images/button_continue-shopping.png"></a></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <?php if($cart->total_items() > 0){ ?>
            <td class="text-center"><strong>Total: <?php echo 'RS'.$cart->total().''; ?></strong></td>
            <td><a href="checkout.php"><img src="images/button_checkout.png <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i><img src="images/button_checkout.png"></a></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: How are you opening modal popup, means where is that code to open modal popup

Comment: i am simply using div id and i am just passing in href tag

Comment: and using the scripts from w3 school

Comment: can any one tell me how to bind action with popup

Comment: use javascript to open href.

Comment: can u tell me how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Instead call one single function on href click and in that function first open popup and then perform your task which you are going to perform.

```
<a class="btnLink" href="#" onclick="demo_funtion(<?php echo $row["PROD_ID"]; ?>)">Add to cart</a>
 function demo_function(cart_id){
    $("#modal_id").show();
    /*
    write task you have to perform in action
    */

 }
```

Comment: how to use it still not getting

Comment: can anyone can help me out with this